# Problem with Dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 (the selected boot device failed)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a laptop (HP 250 G2) that currently runs Windows 8.1. I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 15.04 with the Windows 8.1.

I have tried both live CD and external hard disk but I keep getting this error:

[image]

At least I know that the problem is not from the burning since I can see these on Windows file manager:

[image]
[image]

I used used cyberlink iso viewer to do the burning while I used universal usb installer to do the same for the external hdd.
I have tried disabling secure boot but got the same error.

My pc supports os boot manager, usb hdd, cd/dvd, internal hdd. Pls what should I do?

Comment: Pls this is the third image http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Cp0YqpnGLcU/VVdmZnz_RHI/AAAAAAAABMg/WmLgZusCbYU/s1600/Screenshot%2B(458).png

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain when exactly the error appears. Also clarify if you've set the CD to be the first boot device. The error shown is a Windows error, not Ubuntu, you need to explain exactly what steps you took to see it.

Comment: Can you change boot order to boot from CD and skip OS boot manager?

Comment: NO, I cannot do that